# Convert a list of matrices to only one 2D matrix in Python

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, sift

I have a list of 3960 matrices, which is simply the SIFT descriptors of 3960 images. This is supposed to result in a list of matrices with an unknown number of lines (which of course will depend on the image) and 128 columns (from SIFT descriptors). I am trying to put this list in just one 2D matrix, which the number of lines is the sum of the number of lines of these matrices and 128 columns, however, I am not being able to do that. Here is my code:

```
sift_keypoints = []

#read images from a text file
with open(file_images) as f:
    images_names = f.readlines()
    images_names = [a.strip() for a in images_names]

    for line in images_names:
        print(line)
        #read image
        image = cv2.imread(line,1)
        #Convert to grayscale
        image =cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #SIFT extraction
        sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
        kp, descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(image,None)
        #appending sift keypoints to a list
        sift_keypoints.append(descriptors)

        #here is what I've tried
        sift_keypoints = np.asmatrix(np.asarray(sift_keypoints))
```

The sift_keypoints shape is (1,3960) according to this code, which is, of course, not what I want. How to transform this list in a 2D numpy array?

**EDIT** one simple example that illustrates my problem is the one in the following code

```
#how to convert this list to a matrix with shape (412,128)?
import numpy as np
x=np.zeros((256,128))
y=np.zeros((156,128))
list=[]
list.append(x)
list.append(y)
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem with a simple example, where metrics are of smaller size.

Comment: @ZdaR every loop of the for statement will generate a matrix of shape (x,128) where x is the number of lines that will vary depending on the image and 128 columns are specific of the SIFT descriptor I used. Suppose that the total of lines of different matrices is 39600 with 128 columns. What I want is to vertically concatenate all these matrices in this list to generate a matrix of shape (39600,128). I will try to put a simple example in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.concatenate`:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a = [np.full((2, 3), i) for i in range(3)]
>>> pprint(a)
[array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
 array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]),
 array([[2, 2, 2],                                                                                                  
       [2, 2, 2]])]                                                                                                 
>>> np.concatenate(a, axis=0)                                                                                       
array([[0, 0, 0],                                                                                                   
       [0, 0, 0],                                                                                                   
       [1, 1, 1],                                                                                                   
       [1, 1, 1],                                                                                                   
       [2, 2, 2],                                                                                                   
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 3):

### Solution using `np.row_stack`

Suppose `l` is your list of Numpy arrays of the shape `(n, 128)`.

Suppose that `m` is the total number of lines: the object is to stack all the objects and create a matrix of the shape `(m, 128)`.

We can proceed as follows, using Numpy's **`row_stack`**:

```python
result = np.row_stack(l)
```